# pthreads only one thread being created

Tags: c++, c, thread-safety, pthreads

I don't understand why the first thread is created and runs through the while loop without allowing other threads to run as well. I did unlock specifically before it would go to sleep so other threads would get created. I think I have to create the threads all at once for this to work, but wouldn't that make it non-thread safe?

In main:

```
Producer *producers[NUM_PTHREADS];
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_PTHREADS; i++) {
       tn[i] = i;
       producers[i] = new Producer(producer_id);
       pthread_create(producers[i]->getThread(),NULL,produce,producers[i]);
       pthread_join(*(producers[i]->getThread()),NULL);
       producer_id++;
    }
```

Ran from pthread_create:

```
void *produce(void* elem){
    Producer *producer;
    producer = (Producer*)elem;
    while(1){
       pthread_mutex_lock(&pmutex);
       printf("Hi, this is thread %d\n",producer->getId());
       producer->makeProduct(product_id);
       product_id++;
       printf("Made product with thread: %d, product_id: %d\n",producer->getId(),product_id);
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&pmutex);
       producer->sleep();
    }
 }
```

Example output:

```
Hi, this is thread 0
Made product with thread: 0, product_id: 1
Hi, this is thread 0
Made product with thread: 0, product_id: 2
Hi, this is thread 0
Made product with thread: 0, product_id: 3
Hi, this is thread 0
Made product with thread: 0, product_id: 4
Hi, this is thread 0
Made product with thread: 0, product_id: 5
Hi, this is thread 0
Made product with thread: 0, product_id: 6
Hi, this is thread 0
Made product with thread: 0, product_id: 7
Hi, this is thread 0
Made product with thread: 0, product_id: 8
Hi, this is thread 0
Made product with thread: 0, product_id: 9
Hi, this is thread 0
Made product with thread: 0, product_id: 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This call:

```
 pthread_join(*(producers[i]->getThread()),NULL);
```

Waits until the thread you created on the line just before it to end, and your produce() thread never ends, so you will only ever create 1 thread.

Comment: So, where should I move this line? In it's own for loop after the create? Or, would I not even need it?

Comment: @DfdfSdff If you want to wait for all your threads to finish, then yes, do another loop.

Comment: It makes complete sense. Thank you so much! I'll accept when possible

Answer (score 1):

`pthread_join` waits for a thread to finish, so it waits forever.